# How to make diagram by text only conveniently

Tags: text

The diagram may like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] | 
+------+------+------+------+
```

It's very nice, but I have to idea to make a diagram like this except typing it character by character. So could any body give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get a chance to look at  loops

Comment: Need more context: language, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: I can write a C program for it, but I think it's not the best way to do that.

Comment: @Satya loops? You mean loops in program?

Comment: The keywords to google for would be "ascii art table generator"